# How to use both GestureRecognizers and Effects in Xamarin Forms at the same time?

Tags: xamarin.forms, effects

I have added a tap gesture recognizer to my StackLayout and I want to change the background color when it is tapped so that the user recognizes that the layout has been tapped

```
  <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer 
         Tapped="Preferences_Clicked"
         NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
  </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

Should I use animation for this?

**UPDATE:**
by changing background color, I mean an effect, something like a highlight, just like when you selsct an item in a ListView

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for toggle color

```
   int tapCount=0;
    void Preferences_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        tapCount++;
        var stackLayout = (StackLayout)sender;
        if (tapCount % 2 == 0) {
            stackLayout.BackgroundColor  = Color.Default;
        } else {
            stackLayout.BackgroundColor  =  Color.Accent;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but sorry my question wasn't clear enough, I updated my question

Comment: You need to put all layout  as a Transparent color and use following code
----
void ItemSelected( object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs args )
{
   if ( selected != null )
    {
        selected.SetColors( false );
    }
    selected = (list.SelectedItem as ModelClass);
    selected.SetColors( true );
}

Comment: I don't have a list, I have a stackLayout with a gesture recognizer

Answer (score 0):

I could find my answer, I simply added this bit of code to the Tapped method, and got what I wanted

```
    public async void Preferences_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int _animationTime = 50;
        try
        {
            var layout = (StackLayout)sender;
            await layout.FadeTo(0.5, _animationTime);
            await layout.FadeTo(1, _animationTime);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }       
    }
```